# Django ModelChoiceField Issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've got the following Situation, I have a rather large legacy model (which works nonetheless well) and need one of its fields as a distinct dropdown for one of my forms:

Legacy Table:

```
class SummaryView(models.Model):
...
Period = models.CharField(db_column='Period', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
...

def __str__(self):
    return self.Period

class Meta:
    managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
    db_table = 'MC_AUT_SummaryView'
```

Internal Model:

```
class BillCycle(models.Model):
...
Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name')
Period = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)  
Version = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Version', default=1.0)  
Type = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Type', choices=billcycle_type_choices)  
Association = models.ForeignKey(BillCycleAssociation, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
...

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name
```

Since I don't want to connect them via a Foreign Key (as the SummaryView is not managed by Django) I tried a solution which I already used quite a few times. In my forms I create a ModelChoiceField which points to my Legacy Model:

```
class BillcycleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
period_tmp = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SummaryView.objects.values_list('Period', flat=True).distinct(),
                                    required=False, label='Period')

....

class Meta:
    model = BillCycle
    fields = ['Name', 'Type', 'Association', 'period_tmp']
```

And in my view I try to over-write the Period Field from my internal Model with users form input:

```
def billcycle_create(request, template_name='XXX'):
form = BillcycleModelForm(request.POST or None)

data = request.POST.copy()

username = request.user
print("Data:")
print(data)

if form.is_valid():
    initial_obj = form.save(commit=False)

    initial_obj.ModifiedBy = username
    initial_obj.Period = form.cleaned_data['period_tmp']
    initial_obj.Status = 'Creating...'

    print("initial object:")
    print(initial_obj)

    form.save()
....
```

So far so good:

- Drop Down is rendered correctly
- In my print Statement in the View ("data") I see that the desired infos are there:
  'Type': ['Create/Delta'], 'Association': ['CP'], 'period_tmp': ['2019-12']

Still I get a **Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.** Error in the forms. Any ideas??

Comment: I notice you have `'Name'` as a field in the form, but it's not in your print statement for data. Is that the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just left it out since it has no relevance (is a freetext field, no foreign key or anything)

Comment: What field is that error being generated for?

Comment: The period_tmp field itself